Drag-dropping files into WebView2
I´ve got a WinForms App where a form contains a WebView2 component as big as the form itself. The code below works fine on the form itself, since the WebView2 element lays on top of the form I´m not able to use the drag-drop functionality on the form and I have to use the WebView2´s one. But it doesnt work the way stated below.
this.webView21.AllowExternalDrop = false;

I set the external drop check to false since I dont want the file to be opened in a new window but just getting the file name dropped into the WebView2 element.
private void webView21_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop)) e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
}

private void webView21_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
    label1.Text = files[0];
}

I want to get the (absolute) file name dropped into the view withouth opening a new window.
Like stated above
this.webView21.AllowExternalDrop = true;

just opens the file in a new window. Not desired.
During my "research" people hinted VS´s security concerns where it´s impossible to do this when using VS. Not using VS, not the problem.
I created two breakpoints for both events that never fired once.
Are these events useable at all?
Thanks in advance

You can probably just handle the NewWindowRequested event, check whether the Uri is a file, cancel the popup if it is. E.g., if (new Uri(e.Uri).IsFile) { e.Handled = true; label1.Text = e.Uri; }

Yes, thats probably an acceptable way. Thanks, but why dont the events work in the first place? Am I doing something wrong?

The WebView2 Control is a required container for actual WebView2 object (partially exposed by CoreWebView2). This container is needed to comply with the WinForms infrastructure (and the Designer's requirements). It derives from the Control class, so it brings in some properties, methods and events that belong to the base class. Most of the time, these do just nothing (well, they could have hidden them, as it's done in many other derived Controls in the platform. It's a design choice. It's also a work in progress)

Works nice, thanks
